# Access controller function from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I have a main controller: `MainCtrl` and a function within it: `$scope.ctrlFn`

This function expects an argument and returns a string concatenated to the received argument value.

MainCtrl JS:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', '$timeout', function ($scope, $http, $log, $timeout) {
      $scope.ctrlFn = function(x) {
          return 'some val'+x;
      };

      var customTemp = '<div ng-repeat="c in grid.appScope.someArray">{{c}}<my-directive url="MODEL_COL_FIELD" vvv="ctrlFn(url)"  /></div>';
      $scope.someArray=['a','b','c'];      
      $scope.gridOptions = {};

      $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/500_complex.json')
        .success(function(data) {
          $scope.gridOptions.data = data;

        });
      $scope.gridOptions.rowHeight = 50;  
      $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [

        { name:'eee' },
        { name:'age'  },
        { name:'address.street'}
      ];
      $scope.gridOptions2 = {};
      $scope.gridOptions2.data =[];
      $scope.gridOptions2.rowHeight =400;
      $scope.gridOptions2.columnDefs =[];

      var timer = function() {
        for (i = 1; i < 100; i++) { 
          $scope.gridOptions2.data.push({
            value:i,
            name:'Name'+i,
            url:'https://dummyimage.com/30x30/000/fff&text='+i,
            image:i
          });

        }

        $scope.gridOptions2.columnDefs =[
          {
            name:'image',
            cellTemplate:customTemp,
            width:100
          },
          {
            name:'name',
            cellTemplate:customTemp,
            width:100
          },
          {
            name:'url',
            width:50
          },
          {
            name:'value'
          }
        ];

      };

      $timeout(timer,0);
      console.log($scope.gridOptions);
      console.log($scope.gridOptions2);
    }]);
```

I have a directive: `myDirective` which creates a template and initiates scope values from parent scope variables and functions and displays them. I have managed to pass the scope variables to directive template like with scope `url` but not the value `myValue` which is meant to be assigned the value returned from the parent function.

Directive `myDirective`:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function ($log) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,

        scope: {
          url: '=',
          vvv: '&'
        },

        template: '<div ng-init="u=url; myValue=vvv" >{{u}}-{{myValue}}<img  src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text={{url}}" alt="Smiley face" height="100" width="100"></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

          scope.$watch('url', function(newValue) {
            var url = newValue;
          });
        }
    };
});
```

Here is a plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/yXE3AuZEPwjlmlqpFTNq?p=preview

Comment: What you want to do? Do you want to access your `ctrlFn` of controller in your directive?

Comment: yes @KiranPawar

Answer (score 0):

To access the parent scope from within the directives template, which is rendered within table cells of the `ui grid`, you have to go through `grid.appScope.variableOrFunction`

So to call ctrlFn() I have to:

```
grid.appScope.ctrlFn()
```

working example:http://plnkr.co/edit/yXE3AuZEPwjlmlqpFTNq?p=preview